# Image not loading?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm new to iOS programming and for the life of me I can't figure out why my image is not loading.

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"banana.jpg"];
CGImageRef myBlock = [myImage CGImage];
CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer];
myLayer.contents = (__bridge id) myBlock;
myLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 417, 119);
myLayer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```

Comment: You must pass in the full path of the file to `imageWithContentsOfFile:`.

Comment: Where is the image file? In the app bundle or some other place like the Documents folder?

Comment: Where did you put `banana.jpg`? or asked differently: how do you expect iOS to find the image without a path?

Answer (score 1):

try replace

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"banana.jpg"];
```

with

```
NSString path =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"banana" ofType:@"jpg"];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Or use `imageNamed:`.

Comment: @rmaddy I think the jpg type image should be large, and using `imageNamed:` will be cached. And I alway get large image with `jpg` type from UI.

Comment: You can't judge size by the extension. This could be a 16x16 icon for all we know. But yes, if the image is large and not needed most of the app's lifetime, then `imageWithContentsOfFile:` is better.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right. Image is large just my guess, and if size is small,  `png` type and `imageNamed:` will be better for iOS.